# Can't remove element by ID from vector of non primitive datatypes

Tags: c++, vector, erase-remove-idiom

I have a vector of my user-defined data type `city`. I'm trying to remove an element from this vector by its ID; eventually all cities will be removed from this list in a `while(!cityList.empty())` loop. I plan to use the erase-remove idiom to accomplish this.

However, I'm getting a very gnarly error message when I *make* my code after calling `remove()`. Passing in the `city` object as the third parameter to `remove()` results in this error, as does passing in the (int) ID of the `city`. This error doesn't occur with `erase()`, but does with `remove()`, and also `find()` if I try to use that. Here is the code in question:

```
vector<city> cityList;
cityList.push_back(city(1));
cityList.push_back(city(2));
cityList.push_back(city(3));

city cityToRemove = cityList[0];
int idOfCityToRemove = cityList[0].getID();

remove(cityList.begin(), cityList.end(), cityToRemove);
//remove(cityList.begin(), cityList.end(), idOfCityToRemove);
```

[Here is an updated simple, minimal demo of my problem](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSG5OMVlJQ3NhMEE).

The error message includes *"template argument deduction/substitution failed"* and *"‘city’ is not derived from ‘const _gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>’ "* messages, and I haven't been able to find anything online relating to my problem with the above errors.

Edit: I've modified my code such that I now have:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

vector<city> cityList;
cityList.push_back(city(1));
cityList.push_back(city(2));
cityList.push_back(city(3));

city cityToRemove = cityList[0];
int idOfCityToRemove = cityList[0].getID();
int i;

for (i = 0; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
    cityList.erase(remove_if(cityList.begin(), cityList.end(),  cityList[i] == cityToRemove), cityList.end());
}
//remove(cityList.begin(), cityList.end(), cityToRemove);
//remove(cityList.begin(), cityList.end(), idOfCityToRemove);

return 0;
}

bool operator ==(const city &a, const city &b)
{
    return (a.id == b.id);
}
```

and the error I receive when attempting to compile is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
             from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<city*, std::vector<city> >; _Predicate = bool]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:866:20:   required from _ForwardIterator std::__remove_if(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Predicate) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<city*, std::vector<city> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<bool>]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:936:30:   required from ‘_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<city*, std::vector<city> >; _Predicate = bool]’
main.cpp:30:90:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:234:30: error: expression cannot be used as a function
{ return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
                          ^
```

This is closer, but I'm not sure what is required. The line `main.cpp:30:90` points to the `cityList[i] == cityToRemove` part of my `cityList.erase()` function, however, so I know that the issue is within my comparison expression.

My demo is also updated.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Where?  I see no code in this question.

Comment: It's much preferred to put your code in your post, rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: It's now edited to include code in the post as well as the minimal example.

Comment: @Jthami05: "minimal, complete" means that it needs to be possible to copy and paste the code from your question, and it compile.

Comment: You probably want `std::remove_if`, together with a predicate for testing whether a city has a given ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an `operator ==`:

```
class city {
    public:
        city(int idin);
        int getID();

    private:
        int id;

    friend bool operator==(const city &a, const city &b);
};
```

.

```
bool operator ==(const city &a, const city &b)
{
    return a.id == b.id;
}
```

and also call `erase` as in the [example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: Adding the operator overloading function to my class and calling it in main.cpp with a for loop as `cityList.erase(remove_if(cityList.begin(), cityList.end(),  cityList[i] == cityToRemove), cityList.end());` decreasese the number of errors, but I still get the "required from ‘_ForwardIterator" error and am unable to compile.

Comment: Post the new code, then? And the full error message.